# Thermalization at quantum critical point and quantum many-body scars

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, conformal-field-theory

Quantum scar states are a hot topic in condensed matter physics. **Quantum scars** are the eigenstates of a many-body system (e.g. a spin chain) that weakly violate the **eigenstate thermalization hypothesis** (ETH). The scar states were firstly observed in a spin model called the PXP model
$$H = \sum_i P_{i-1}X_i P_{i+1}$$
where $\{X_i,Y_i,Z_i\}$ are spin-1/2 Pauli matrices and $P_i=(1-Z_i)/2$ the projective operator that projects out the cases that two neighboring spins being polarized up simultaneously.
(for details see the paper [Turner et. al](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.98.155134)).

Quantum scar states have the following properties:

**i)** towering states are the scar states whose expectation w.r.t. local observable deviates from the thermal average, e.g. $\langle Z_1 \rangle$ see the figure (a) below (intercepted from [Turner et. al](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.98.155134)), where the blue curve denoted by 'Canonical' is the canonical ensemble prediction (thermal average). It is evidence of breaking the ETH;

**ii)** lower bipartite entropy which scales with the system size $L$ in the way of $\log L$ (log-volume law);

**iii)** roughly separated by equal energy intervals within the spectrum, see the figure (a) and (b) below where $E$ is the energy and $S$ is the bipartite von Neumann entropy. In the figure, the numbered states (labeled by 0,1,...,7) are the scar states separated by equal energy intervals $\Delta E$.

[image: figures related to scar states]

Due to the above features, the scars leads to anomolous dynamical behaviors such as **dynamical revival** and **incomplete thermalization**. Let us now explane them one-by-one.

**Dynamical revival**: for certain states, say $|\mathbb{Z}_2\rangle$, which is Neel-ordered state with spins polarized up and down alternatively. In the quench dynamics $|\psi(t)\rangle = \exp(-i H t) |\mathbb{Z}_2\rangle$, $|\psi(t)\rangle$ will periodically goes back to the initial state $|\mathbb{Z}_2\rangle$ in period $T$, see figure (c). This phonemon is easy to understand since the $|\mathbb{Z}_2\rangle$ is mainly constructed by the scar states and hence the revival period relates to the energy intervals $\Delta E$ by $T = 2\pi/\Delta E$.

**Incomplete thermalization**: thermalization refers to the phenomenon that, after long-time evolution, the system will finally approach a 'stationary' state $|\psi(t)\rangle$ such that the expectation of any local observable $\langle\psi(t)| O_\text{local} |\psi(t)\rangle$ is right equal to the microcanonical ensemble average $\text{Tr}(O_\text{local} \rho_{th})$ with $\rho_{th}$ the microscopic thermal density matrix. However, the thermalization is broken for the aforementioned $|\mathbb{Z}_2\rangle$ dynamics after long-time evolution, which hence is called the **Incomplete thermalization**.

Very recently, Z. Yao and et al studied the PXP model with a longitudinal field (see [arXiv:
2108.05113v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.05113v1))
$$H = \sum_i P_{i-1}X_i P_{i+1} - m \sum_i Z_i,$$
and they observed that the additional m term would lead to a 2nd-order phase transition ($m_c=0.655$) belonging to the Ising universality class (Ising CFT).
Just at the critical point, they observe the thermalization of the $|\mathbb{Z}_2\rangle$ dynamics has resumed (at the same time dynamical revivals disappear). The figure below (intercepted from [arXiv:
2108.05113v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.05113v1)) shows the long-time evolution of the $|\mathbb{Z}_2\rangle$ state in the cases of $m<m_c$, $m=m_c$ and $m>m_c$ with red dashed line indicating the thermal average w.r.t. local observable $Z_1$.
[image: Z2-state dynamics]

This is an interesting phenomenon that concerns me a lot, and I have the following two questions unclear:

**(1) Whether we can make a general conclusion that the thermalization will restore at quantum criticality?**

**(2) What is the mechanism of the thermalization at the critical point? Can this phenomenon be explained by the conformal field theory (CFT)?**

I'm trying to figure these out from the CFT end, but making little progress, and if anyone would like to give some advice.